# PHP string key in array gives Undefined index

Tags: php, undefined

I have the following array:

```
Array
(
    [A3L791B03M-YLWS] => 1
    [A3L791B03MBLKS5] => 1
    [A3L791B05M-BLKS] => 2
    [A3L791B05M-BLU] => 1
    [A3L791B05M-BLUS] => 1
    [A3L791B05M-GRY] => 2
    [A3L791B05M-H-S] => 1
    [A3L791B05M-REDS] => 1
    [A3L791B05M-S] => 2
    [A3L791B05M-WHTS] => 2
    [A3L791B05M-YLWS] => 2
    [A3L791B10M-BLKS] => 2
    [A3L791B10M-BLUS] => 2
    [A3L791B10M-GRNS] => 1
    [A3L791B10M-GRY] => 2
    [A3L791B10M-REDS] => 1
    [A3L791B10M-S] => 3
    [A3L791B10M-S?KIT] => 1
    [A3L791B10M-WHTS] => 2
    [A3L791B10M-YLWS] => 1
)
```

However, when I try to call for the data of A3L791b10M-S via:

```
echo $array_mysku_count['A3L791b10M-S'];
```

However, when I do so, I get the following error:

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Notice: Undefined index: A3L791b10M-S in...

All the other keys seems to be fine. Anything that is specific about this key that is causing this?

Answer (score 2):

You're using the key `A3L791b10M-S` but it's actually `A3L791B10M-S`. Note the uppercase `B` there.

Answer (score 2):

`A3L791B10M-S` is different from `A3L791b10M-S`. Watch the case...

Answer (score 1):

Change the b to upper case.

```
A3L791B10M-S
```

You also may be interested in the [`strtoupper`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtoupper.php) function.